# Read custom configuration from conf directory

Tags: xml, scala, playframework, stream, readfile

I'm building a web application using 'Play Framework 2.5' and I have planned to place a custom XML file inside the conf/ directory of the application. This file will contain some information used to populate some meta-tag to help search engines to index my public web pages. The question is how I can open this file (named searchEngines.xml) from a controller's action?

When the file will be open (so I have a stream with it) I can easily read and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward

```
Source.fromFile("conf/your-file-name.xml")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. When my project will be finished and I publish my project the command still work again? I have read that, in distribution mode, the conf directory is outside from the classpath.

Comment: What is distributed mode? If you are centralizing your application configurations, with a single point of configuration, you'll have to change that path obviously.

Comment: Now, because I'm writing it I execute with the activator run command, but from different guide I read that there is the activator dist command that build an "executable" ready for the production environment

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Play.application.resourceAsStream("your-config-file-name.xml")
```

as mentioned on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299542/load-file-from-conf-directory-on-cloudbees)